# Why I got an Error: Can't display popup. Could not find view with tag XXX when using UIManager.showPopupMenu() method in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

**Hello Everyone!**

I want to show a native popup menu in Android using `UIManager.showPopupMenu()` method, but I got an Error `Can't display the popup. Could not find view with tag XXX` at the docs the first parameter of that method should be filled with a view tag number using the `findNodeHandle()` method.

It works fine if I am using a `ref` from `<Pressable ref={handlePopupRef} />` but It doesn't work if I am using a `ref` from `<View ref={handlePopupRef}></View>`

I have no idea what's wrong with my code even when I am trying with `ref callback` it still doesn't work like `<View ref={ref => handlePopupRef.current = ref}></View>`

**Code Samples**

**Icon.tsx**

```
import React, {forwardRef, RefAttributes} from 'react';
import {View, StyleProp, TextStyle} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

interface IconHelperProps {
  name?: string;
  size?: number;
  color?: string;
  style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
}

const IconHelper: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
  IconHelperProps & RefAttributes<null>
> = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <View ref={ref}>
      <Icon
        name={props.name || 'help-circle'}
        size={props.size || 24}
        color={props.color || '#242424'}
        style={[props.style]}
      />
    </View>
  );
});

export default IconHelper;
```

**Button.tsx**

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Pressable,
  UIManager,
  findNodeHandle,
  StyleProp,
  TextStyle,
  ViewStyle,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from './Icon';
import Text from './Text';

export interface ButtonHelperProps {
  title?: string;
  iconName?: string;
  iconSize?: number;
  iconColor?: string;
  isDropdown?: boolean;
  dropdownMenu?: string[];
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  textStyle?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
  onPress?: () => void;
  onPressDropdownMenu?: (i: number | undefined) => void;
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonHelperProps> = props => {
  const {title, iconName, isDropdown} = props;
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState('transparent');
  const handlePopupRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <Pressable
      onPressIn={() => {
        setBgColor('#E3E3E7');
      }}
      onPress={() => {
        if (isDropdown) {
          UIManager.showPopupMenu(
            findNodeHandle(handlePopupRef.current),
            props.dropdownMenu || ['Sample Menu'],
            error => {
              console.log(error);
              console.error('Error Show Popup');
            },
            (e, i) => {
              props.onPressDropdownMenu?.(i);
            },
          );
        } else {
          props.onPress?.();
        }
      }}
      onPressOut={() => {
        setBgColor('transparent');
      }}
      style={[
        {
          backgroundColor: bgColor,
          borderRadius: title ? 8 : 0,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
        },
        props.style,
      ]}
    >
      // It's work fine when I am using a Ref from Pressable component
      {/* {isDropdown && <Pressable ref={handlePopupRef}></Pressable>} */}

      // But it doesn't work when I am using a Ref from View component
      {iconName && (
        <Icon
          name={iconName}
          size={props.iconSize}
          color={props.iconColor}
          ref={ref => (handlePopupRef.current = ref)}
        />
      )}

      {title && (
        <Text
          size={14}
          bold
          style={[
            {
              paddingHorizontal: 24,
              paddingVertical: 12,
            },
            props.textStyle,
          ]}
        >
          {title}
        </Text>
      )}
    </Pressable>
  );
};

export default Button;
```